# ggplot: Set location of bins in geom_bin2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to customize the exact (x,y) locations of the bin centers (or starting points) when drawing a 2d histogram in `ggplot`, for example centering the bins on integer values. When using `geom_histogram`, I can pass arguments `center`, `boundary` and `breaks` to control the binning process exactly. None of these are defined    for `geom_bin2d` or `stat_bin2d`. I can change the number of bins and the width but not the starting position - it seems like the range of the data also has an effect.

Comment: The most direct way may be to (unfortunately) define the bins yourself, using `cut` (or similar) to count things.

Comment: Depending on your data, you may find `geom_count` to be useful. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_count.html